# jQuery loop + traversing getting the array number / position of the object on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So here is my problem.. the inputs appear in the same order as the span tag. I.e. :input[0] will match span[0]. However, I am not sure how my script will be able to see what the array number of the object is. Any suggestions? Note, var al is not an integer.

```
<script>
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $(":input").each(function() {
        if($(this).val() === "")
            var al = $(this).eq();

            $('span:eq('+al+')').fadeIn();
        });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback provided to each will get the [index of the currently processed element](http://api.jquery.com/each/) passed:

```
<script>
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $(":input").each(function(al) {
            if($(this).val() === "")

                $('span:eq('+al+')').fadeIn();
            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I came up with powered with the remembrance of index values.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$(":input").each(function(index, value) { 
  alert(index + ': ' + value); 
});
```

The foreach function can index as an argument in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

use index property like, `$(":input").each(function(index){...}` to get the index. and then use jquery `.get( [index] )` for your spans.

Comment: oh nice, I never knew how to use index properly

Comment: `$('#submit').click(function(){
  $(":input").each(function(iVal) {
      if($(this).val() === "")
       $('span:eq('+iVal+')').fadeIn();
   });
 });`